# What happens when we write delay instruction twice continuously in an MSP430?

Tags: msp430

What happens when we write a delay instruction twice continuously in MSP430 code as follows:

```
void delay();
{
    __delay_cycles(1000); 
    __delay_cycles(1000);
}
```

For 1  cycle delay time is 1ms if we add another what happens?

Comment: What happened when you tested it?  This is just a C function call, so it will be called twice.

Comment: Are you looking for the obvious answer that it roughly doubles the delay or are you after a cycle-perfect type answer? If the latter you'd need probably need to include the assembler listing of that section of code generated by the compiler.

Comment: It also may help to mention which compiler you are using : gcc-4.9 with the official msp430 backend doesn't support intrinsics such as delay_cycles yet.

Comment: @brian if op found it wasn't supported, naturally they would be asking why it doesn't compile.

Comment: @david it is not just a c function, it is an intrinsic function.

Answer (score 5):

__delay_cycles(const int) is an intrinsic function. That means the compiler substitutes predesigned assembly for the function, and it is not optimized in any way by the optimizer in the compiler. Inserting it twice means that the delay is doubled, and code wise, two sets of the same code run back to back. It is not optimized to be a longer delay. A subtle but key difference.

Keep in mind, this is the same reason __delay_cycles only takes a constant, and not a variable. It is analyzed at compile time and **cannot** function as a run time function.